# Options for searching

Tags: support, search

I recently asked a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193068/number-of-results-doesnt-add-up). And the answer included `is:question`.

Where does one find the available options for searching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search, click "*Advanced search tips*" on the right.

Then a link is provided to Advanced Search Options in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of posterity/completion, if you want to look for information on site features, a good starting point is by going to the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) (click "*help*" on the header) and use the search feature there.

So, let's say you type "*Options for searching*" in Help Center's search. The ["How do I search?" help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) comes up as [the first result](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=options+for+searching).